# Calculate expectation of win in a Slot Machine

Tags: probability, combinatorics, gambling

I want to calculate the win expectation in a Slot Machine with 3 Reels, including wild (W) symbols
R1=[A,B,C,D]
R2=[A,B,C,D,W,W,W]
R3=[A,B,W,W,W,C,D]
After a spin of the 3 reels we get a 3x3 window.

The payments are 1 for doubles of A,B,C,D and 2 for triplets.
Wild (W) may substitute left to right:

- [A,W,C] is [A,A,C] pays 2.
- [A,B,W] payment is 0.
- If W in a columns of the 2nd or 3rd all 3 symbols are converted to W.

  R1 R2 R3
  A  C  C
  B  D  D
  C  W  A

we can substituite and get (wich will pay 6)

```
R1 R2 R3
A  W  C
B  W  D
C  W  A
```

So, the expectation to get 3 A is:
if X1 is the event to get a symbol in the first reel in a line, and R1 the event to get at least 1 W in reel 1, then I get:

P(3A) = P(X1 = A) * P( R2 = A or X2 = A) * P( R3 = A or X3 = A) =
1/4 * ( 5/7 + 1/7)^2 =  0.18
So the expectation to get a triplet is 0.73

I would like to check if this is correct, and how to calculate expected win of doubles. P(2A)

I have tested with an script and I get : 137% of payback: 1*P(2A) + 2*P(3A)

Can you help me to build the correct combinatories and the expected payback ?

Comment: Hard to follow the rules.  What does "$W$ may substitute left to right" mean?  Why doesn't $[A,B,W]=[A,B,B]$?  (I am guessing these two questions have the same answer).  Do doubles (or triples) only matter in a single row?

Comment: W is only able to replace Reel 1

Comment: See...the rules sound a bit like [Calvinball](https://calvinandhobbes.fandom.com/wiki/Calvinball).  And if I then ask why $[A,B,W]$ isn't $[A,B,A]$ for a two point double, I'm sure there will be a brand new rule.  I suspect it's too hard for anyone here to guess the full rule set.

Comment: More broadly:  In situations with a complex rule set, it's often easier to solve it numerically than it is to work it out analytically.  If you have the full rule set, you can program it, then run it repeatedly. Or, as here where there are fewer than $4\times 7\times 7$ possible outcomes, simply list all of them after which you can read off the result you want.  This has the advantage that a rule change is just a simple programming correction, rather than a major disruption.